# Issue in System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke when debugging ASP.NET Core 3 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 3 Razor Page app in VS2019.  I have started to get a message, "To prevent an unsafe abort when evaluating the function 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke' all threads were allowed to run..."

[image]

Can someone tell what is going on and how to resolve it?  Thanks

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187355/visual-studio-2017-debug-error-to-prevent-an-unsafe-abort-when-evaluating-the-f?rq=1) which may be helpful .

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764510/visual-studio-2019-error-pop-up-appears-to-prevent-an-unsafe-abort-when-evalu/58797847#58797847