# VS 2022: Managed Compatibility Mode gone. How do I disable "To prevent an unsafe abort..." dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

My co-worker encountered a bug today using Visual Studio 2022 that has long been a "solved problem" here on Stack overflow.   The problem is a dialog that appears every time she debugs our application

[image: Annoying dialog]

The accepted SO solution (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187355/visual-studio-2017-debug-error-to-prevent-an-unsafe-abort-when-evaluating-the-f) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764510/visual-studio-2019-error-pop-up-appears-to-prevent-an-unsafe-abort-when-evalu), and other places) is for the user to change the General Debug Options to "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".

Unfortunately, I no longer see that option in VS 2022 General Debug Options.

Did the option just move elsewhere or is it gone?  If it's gone, is there another way to prevent this dialog from showing?

Comment: I would consider fixing the underlying problem. It appears that either you have a very complex expression in one of your watch windows or you do some complex reflection tasks inside a properties `get` method.

Comment: Neither of those, unfortunately.  And she is the only one who gets the error.

Comment: I suppose you have tried to clean the solution, and all the other obvious things if a problem happens only on one computer?

Comment: I am told by the co-worker that she has but I wasn't watching over her shoulder.   After she told me that I took her word for it and searched here.  I found the workaround and then wondered why it was no longer available.  So I posted my question.  Then someone (you?) posted that it was fixed in 17.0.5 and she was on 17.0.4 so she's updated.  The comment it gone now but I had her update.  If it persists I'll watch her do all the clean stuff that I would normally do.

Comment: No, that wasn't me over there. I had no idea so I posted the obvious...

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio 2020
go to tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> disable (Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls)

Comment: I do not downvote this answer, but no, this is not the idea. Property evaluation is a valuable feature. If we go further that way we'd better stop debugging at all.

Comment: This does not resolve the problem for me.

Comment: Upvoting - without this option, and in this particular scenario, no debugging at all is possible. With this option, at least some limited debugging is possible